# How-to restore duplicity/duply backup from unknown archive

Tags: backup, restore, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I've multiple virtual machines and every machine is backuping to the same backup storage (GlusterFS; it's mounted using fuse), but into different backup directories. `/var/www/` for example will be backuped to this directory:

```
    /mnt/backup/server001/duply/www/
    /mnt/backup/server002/duply/www/
    /mnt/backup/server003/duply/www/
    ...
    /mnt/backup/serverXXX/duply/www/
    ...
```

As backup software, I'm using duply / duplicity. If I know, on which server the folder or file was, I can connect to this server and run this command to restore it:

```
    duply www-backup fetch www.example.com/ /var/www/www.example.com/ 1D
```

Unfortunatley, this does only work for files and directories, which were backuped from/on this server.

Today, I've the problem, that I've deleted a while a go a website and can't remember myself, on which server it was hosted. Well... This means, I would need to connect to each single host and need to run the restore command to check, if it's available from there or not.

I don't have the time to do this on each single server. Well... Is there a way to fetch it from the backup anyhow using file://, even when I don't know, where it is?

I've already tried to fetch it using the following command, but it didn't worked, because the directories does not contain any backup chain:

```
    duplicity --force file:///mnt/backup/ /var/www/www.example.com/
```

Any ideas?

```
    # duplicity --version
    duplicity 0.6.23
```

Answer (score 1):

yes,

if you have local or otherwise access to this GlusterFS storage and eg. assuming it would be mounted under /mnt/backup/ you can list and restore from it using the file target.

i'd suggest listing/grepping first and when you found the backup repo containing your folder restoring from there

repeat this for every backup folder (note the three slashes in the target url for an absolute file path)

```
duplicity list-current-files [options] [--time time] file:///mnt/backup/server[num]/duply/www/
```

then restore when you found the folder (use the folder name as shown in the listing, a relative path to the backup base folder)

```
duplicity [restore] [options] --file-to-restore www.example.com [--time time] /mnt/backup/server[num]/duply/www/ /var/www/www.example.com
```

parameters in [square brackets] are optional.

hope that helps.. ede/duply.net

Comment: Sounds good. Unfortunately, the listing command is now copying all signature files from the GlusterFS storage to the local cache to get the listing. This takes a lot of time. I'm already waiting for more than 15 minutes for only one server... Can't I say, that it has to read it from the remote side?